# Transformer classification model for float data

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I'm trying make a transformer classification model by PyTorch and the input is `torch.FloatTensor(float data)`. But, I'm getting hard time with dealing embedding layer since the data is float tensor, it's hard to choose vocal size. Moreover, even I use embedding layer by passing the input as long type, during training `CUDA error: device-side assert triggered` occurs which seems to be from out of range of the input. Is there any way to build transformer classifier that can get float data as input?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the problem is the tensor type, you can try some simple code like:
import torch

```
from torch.nn import Transformer

model = Transformer().cuda()
src = torch.rand((10, 32, 512)).float().cuda()
tgt = torch.rand((20, 32, 512)).float().cuda()

print(model(src, tgt).shape)
```

and see that the output is correct as: torch.Size([20, 32, 512]). Please check out:

- Inconsistency between the number of labels/classes and the number of output units
- The input of the loss function may be incorrect.